# PostGIS ST_Length returns 0 for geographies with high number of decimals

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-distance

I'm having a weird issue when computing the distance between two geographies using ST_Length (PostgreSQL 10.4, PostGIS 2.4.4). Basically if the number of decimals is above six, ST_Length returns 0 in some cases.

Using ST_Length as it is shown in [the documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html):

```
# SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist
    FROM (SELECT
        ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-122.4367398 37.7370600, -122.4376093 37.7371769)') As gg1,
        ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-122.4367539 37.7371343, -122.4375453 37.7372407)') As gg2
    ) As foo ;
 spheroid_dist | sphere_dist 
---------------+-------------
             0 |           0

# -- Remove 7th decimal
# SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist
    FROM (SELECT
        ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-122.436739 37.737060, -122.437609 37.737176)') As gg1,
        ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-122.436753 37.737134, -122.437545 37.737240)') As gg2
    ) As foo  ;
 spheroid_dist | sphere_dist 
---------------+-------------
     7.8956756 |  7.90923387
```

What's weird is that the issue doesn't occur every time:

```
# SELECT ST_Distance(gg1, gg2) As spheroid_dist, ST_Distance(gg1, gg2, false) As sphere_dist
    FROM (SELECT
        ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-122.4363981 37.7371789,-122.4366807 37.7370670)') As gg1,
        ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;LINESTRING(-122.4363905 37.7372617,-122.4366961 37.7371407)') As gg2
    ) As foo ;
 spheroid_dist | sphere_dist 
---------------+-------------
     7.9257293 |  7.93355247
```

What could be the reason for this? Feels like it's a float/double issue but I don't see why the problem would only occur in some cases.

Comment: adding an extra (8th) decimal makes it return the expected distance, so it might be more than just a rounding issue

Comment: Good call, definitely looks like a bug then. Interestingly enough, in the original data there's actually 12 decimals, and if I try randomly dropping some of them the results are sometimes right and sometimes wrong... I'll reach out to the postgis support

Answer (score 0):

The first query gives this result for me:

```
spheroid_dist | sphere_dist 
--------------+-------------
7.92351961      7.93711061
```

My PostGIS version is

> POSTGIS=""3.4.1 3.4.1"" [EXTENSION] PGSQL=""160""
> GEOS=""3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1"" SFCGAL=""SFCGAL 1.5.0, CGAL 5.6, BOOST
> 1.78.0"" PROJ=""8.2.1

Maybe the bug has been corrected.